# Full content view mode per role

Tags: users, display-suite

I've looked around but didn't find the right solution. In D7.5x I would like to create different view modes (of Full Content) per role. I am using Display Suite.

The situation should be like this: I have teaser view mode, Full content (limited) view mode, Full Content (extra) view mode. Is there any quick solution, to let users with role A after clicking onto link in teaser view mode get to see Full content (limited) and users with role B get Full content (extra)?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Oh, It looks like I've found an answer myself, so I will post it here in case someone will have similar issue. One of the solutions (I am still not sure if this is the optimal one, but it works) is to use module Contextual View Modes (It requires Context module and Entity API). With this combination of modules it is possible to create context rules where in Conditions section there is particular user role and in Reactions one must define particular View mode for Content Type. And that's it! It just requires at least 3 modules to be installed, so maybe there is some simplier solution...